# What is the current way to access user's photos via Google Plus api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-plus

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm need to allow users to access their Google Plus albums and photos.

After a lot of searching, I'm very confused as to what is the currently accepted best practice to do this (in part this is because Google seems to be in the process of transitioning these products and APIs).

Ideally I would like to remain entirely within the Google Plus api and avoid Picassa (this product appears to be on the way out..?).

I'd appreciate some advice

1. Can photos, albums, videos, etc be accessed via the Google Plus api.
2. Is there a good up-to-date guideline for integrating Google Plus photos with Rails.
3. What gems should I be looking at (I already have Google oauth working in the app, I've examined the google_plus gem but it appears to access user profiles and activities, but not photos/albums).

Has anyone managed to integrate Google Plus photos into a Rails app?

Or has anyone managed to access photos via the Google Plus api at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plus API & photos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831277/google-plus-api-photos)

Comment: Hi @Mechanical snail, this question is not a duplicate. Not only does it precede the question you link to by several weeks, but it also specifically mentions wanting to avoid Picassa's API

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/timmykat/google_plus is a point to start, I think.

Comment: thanks @alex, I have examined the google_plus gem, but I cannot seem to access photos and albums. Am I missing some syntax?

Comment: I haven't found any ruby bindings to google plus photos API. You may implement required features yourself in gem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem right now with an Android app. I implemented the Google+ API to log-in and get basic user info and profile picture. But there doesn't seem to be a way to query the user's photos or albums.

Unfortunately after searching online it seems like the only way to currently do this is via the [Picasa Web Album API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol), which is super annoying. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11378171/2395750) links to [an article](http://siliconfilter.com/google-gets-an-api-for-photos-and-videos/) from 2011 about a Google employee accidentally leaking that photo/album support was coming to the Google+ API, but it seems that never happened.