# Google Plus API & photos?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, picasa

As I understand, there's no official G+ API for getting photos from albums.
But I've figured out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183212/google-plus-album-urls) that Google Plus uses Picasa internally.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to figure out only via G+ API Picasa userId?
2. If yes, how can I do it with G+ API if I only have the Google Plus page URL(something like this: https://plus.google.com/104560124403688998123 - or -  https://plus.google.com/115999964287637644901) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link you "figured it out from" tells what you need to know.  That first big number in the page URL is the UserID.  From there you can call something like:

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/115999964287637644901

and it will give you a list of the albums available.  Drill down from there.

Downside?  Sometime soon Google is no doubt going to change all this by implementing a real G+ API for photos.

Comment: ...or maybe just change the API for Google Photos, now that Google Plus seems to be a back-burner project. https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/

Comment: Hi if i pass my user id i cant see my uploaded photos other than profile pic, please help me out