# Android API for Google+ Photos

Tags: java, android, google-plus

Is there any better way to access google plus photo album beside [picasa web api](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java)? I'm looking for way to pull my own g+ photostream to build a chromecast app. I looked at the [android g+ api](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/package-summary.html) and there aren't any photo api.

Similar questions for other platforms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831277/google-plus-api-photos) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579477/what-is-the-current-way-to-access-users-photos-via-google-plus-api)

Comment: You need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183212/google-plus-album-urls

Comment: Yeah that use the picasa-web api. Ideally I would like to use something that leverage google's android service a bit more like the image syncing and account authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found all the pieces for that I need. The end result is to use AccountManager to get the auth token and PicasawebService to do the rest. Though there are some annoying bug with adapting the class. I wrote up my little adventure here along with example code.

http://roostertech.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/accessing-gphoto-android/